# jQuery Ajax not sending Post data to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm trying to send variables from my JavaScript to a PHP file using AJAX but it's not working. I've looked through all the similar asked questions (there are a bunch) but have yet to find a solution.

**This is my first php file (one with the form, sends data to JavaScript):**

```
<option value="imageOne" data-cuteform-image='assets/SketchThumbnails/imageOne.png></option>
<input id="inputURLID" type="text" name="inputURL">

<button type="submit" onclick="handleInputs(document.getElementById('sketch').value, document.getElementById('inputURLID').value); return false;">Submit</button>
```

**JavaScript (where AJAX call is)**:

```
var content = {
    'sketch': pickedSketch,
    'songUrl': enteredURL
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "loadSketch.php",
    data: content,
    success: function (data, text) {
        // alert("success");
        // console.log(data);
        // console.log(text);

        window.location.href = "loadSketch.php";

    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

**PHP (loadSketch.php):**

```
if(isset($_POST['songUrl']))
{
    $temp = $_POST['songUrl'];
    echo $temp;
    echo "received AJAX data";
} else {
    echo "nothing in post variable";
}
```

When I get redirected to loadSketch.php (from the successful ajax call), "nothing in post variable" gets echoed out. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Any insight is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is in songURL because when your Ajax function returns it is redirecting to the same page you just posted to.  It is creating a new HTTP request to that PHP file with no data sending to it.  Remove the comments on the console messages and you'll see the correct echo messages.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "loadSketch.php",
data: content,
success: function (data, text) {
    alert("success");
    console.log(data);

},
error: function (request, status, error) {
    alert(request.responseText);
}
});
```

Comment: What if I want to redirect to loadSketch.php and deal with the data variables in that file?

Comment: Then AJAX is not what you should be using.  Just a simple HTML form and action to that PHP file is what you want.

Comment: the problem is that the file i want to go to (loadSketch.php for example) is dependent on those variables. ie if sketch is 1, then it will go to 1.php, etc etc

Comment: @Suraya Why would you want to redirect to the same file you just posted to with AJAX? If you have to determine the action to take depending on the posted data, you'll want to do that in PHP.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp is right.  AJAX is for "asynchronous" operations, as the name proclaims.  You're apparently not needing that.  PHP can handle what you need done all in one file.

Comment: When looking up how to execute a function in PHP on a button's click, most sources say to use AJAX. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: @Suraya You can use AJAX to do this, it's just probably not necessary.  But, if you do, instead of redirecting to the same PHP file, Use that file to return another file to redirect to based on the post data sent to it.  Do your work in that first PHP file and then tell JS what to do. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a submit button because it makes the whole page reload; instead use normal buttons and handle the click events calling your AJAX function.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="doAjaxFunction(param1, param2);">Calling Ajax Function<button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function doAjaxFunction(val1,val2){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "loadSketch.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {"'value1':'"+ val1+"', 'value2':'"+ val2+"'"},
    success: function (data, text) {
    // alert("success");
    // console.log(data);
    // console.log(text);
    window.location.href = "loadSketch.php";
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

Then just pick your POST parameters in `loadSketch.php` and use them.

PHP:

```
$x = $_POST['value1'];
$y = $_POST['value2'];
```

Comment: @H.DJEMAI Instead of adding useless bold formatting to all-caps, consider replacing it, and use as little formatting as is appropriate. Also, try to find all grammar or spelling errors.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks for your help and feedback.